# IPN response with 200 HTTP code but nothing in my database

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I really need help because I don't know what to do at this point. I developed a website where the new user need to pay for sign up, I set the correct paypal form button and about the money everything works ok, the problem is that I can't update my database. I'm using these files (they are provided on gitHub and also in the official Paypal guide there's a link to them): "PaypalIPN.php" and "example_usage.php". I also added to my Ubuntu cloud server (where is my website) the cert/cacert.pem, I don't know if I had to do but in the first file seems to be required.

I tried to run a IPN simulator but it doesn't work, I looked for the same problem and I found that there may be a problem with the simulator, so I made some real transactions (I've read that live production test is run correctly with that code).
Therefore:

- the transaction money is ok;
- in the Instant payment notification history there are all test I made and in message ID I can read the correct data passed in the IPN message, the IPN type is "Transaction executed" and the response code is 200. I noticed that in "example_usage.php" the 200 response code was out of the if ($verified) so, just for my last test, I put that inside the if and yes, the response was again that;
- I tried my code for update the mongodb database with fake data and obviously it works.

How is it possible? Please, help me and thank you.

Comment: Welcome! To ask [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you.**

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify the correct URL is showing in the IPN History details?  Sometimes people are using a button that uses notify_url to override the PayPal account setting, and then IPNs are working, but they're going to a different place than expected.  So check that first.

If the IPN is indeed going to the URL you expect, and it's returning a 200 OK, that means it's receiving and completing the script successfully.  If you aren't seeing the expected result in your database then you must have some sort of a logic problem with your code that needs to be addressed.  You need to build in some trackers to log files or send yourself emails as it does each step of your script to see if that portion of code is actually getting hit like you think it is.

I put together this article for [how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn) a while back that has proven helpful for many people.  If you follow the steps there you should be able to track down the problem.

Comment: Thank you! Anyway, I solved the problem: the directory (where are my ssl certificates) didn't have the permission for being read, so I changed the permissions with chmod.